# Where do deb packages install to

Tags: 12.04, installation, deb

I installed a deb package via the commandline like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver_2.1.0_i386.deb
```

I want to install some drivers for the software and to do so I need to place them in the root directory of the application, so where did the package install to?

Comment: There's no root directory for the application (unless that term is used in some special way by the authors of that particular app). The files installed from the package are not contained in any single master folder. You'll have to provide more information about exactly what you're trying to do. Files from `.deb` packages are installed throughout the filesystem, in accordance with the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). You can run `dpkg -L packagename` (*without* the `.deb`) to list a package's installed files, but that might not help.

Answer (score -1):

As stated on the comments, that concept of application root directory generally don't apply to Ubuntu packages, but to compressed archives (.tar.gz or .zip, for example) that you can extract to somewhere you want. There the root directory may be the directory you extracted (if the compressed file contains a directory).

In your specific case, the application root seems to be in `/usr/share/dbeaver`. You can try to place there the files but you will need root permission. Also it is not a very good solution, so check one of the following options first.

<strike>In your case, you seem to be trying to install [this](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/), and the manual driver installation should only be needed if you downloaded the `.zip` version. From the website:</strike>

> Note: Generally you don’t need to download this archive. It may be useful if you are going to use DBeaver in an environment without internet access.

So check if the application don't comes already with those drivers. If not check if it has not a functionality inside the application to install them.

Indeed the application allows you to install the drivers, but for some reason the installation always fails (on the .deb version, maybe because of no write permission). So you have two options:

1. Download the .zip version and uninstall the .deb version: after you download just extract the folder contained on that archive and place it wherever you want. The root directory of the application will be that directory so you just place there the needed .jar's. If it doesn't work try place them on the `plugins` subdir.
2. You will have to specify the paths to the drivers on the application. Go to "Database" -> "Driver manager". There select the driver you want and press "Edit". You will see something asking you to install the driver. Press "OK".

[image]

It will then probably fail but press "Ignore". You will see the following screen:

[image]

delete the red item (by selecting it and pressing "Delete") and use "Add Folder" to specify the location where you extracted the JDBC drivers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found the root: `/usr/shared/dbeaver` I was able to copy the files there and got it running!

Comment: Thanks for the excellent edit! Please note that `.deb` files are, among other things, compressed archives. But its files extract to absolute paths, not all inside a newly created directory. (This can be accomplished with many other archive types, too, including `.tar`, by the way.) That's a small detail, but you may want to edit the top of your answer to account for it, so that people are not surprised to find a `.tar` archive whose contents get extracted all over the place. (A bad experience if that's not one's intention.)